# How to use where method in python when getting error everytime?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, where-clause

I am trying to apply a `.where` function to this data frame so that it filters by pitch type, but am getting the error "Array conditional must be same shape as self" every-time. Never had this issue with any past data frames,

[image: included an image of the error]

as well as

[image: an image of the column in the dataframe]

Comment: What is `are` ?

Comment: Please post your code as text and not as a picture. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what `are.equal_to` is, but this should work for you:

```
fastball = march[march["TaggedPitchType"] == "Fastball"]
```